# Generate code coverage of coffeescript with webpack and karma

Tags: coffeescript, webpack, karma-runner, code-coverage

Is there any way to generate accurate code coverage for Coffeescript using Webpack and Karma? There is not much literature on the internet to get this working. I have tried to use karma-sourcemap-loader to no avail.